# Tourist visa refused after WHV

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, tourist-visas, working-holiday

I recently spent 2 years in Australia working with my Working Holiday Visa. In this time I did little to no sightseeing. In almost all cases I was asked to stay longer by my employers.

My plan was to save as much money as possible over the two years so I could fund my continuous travels around the world.

I saved $30,000 in the 2 years I worked in Australia and wanted to do the East Coast over 2 months, fly from Brisbane to Bali and then travel Asia. In doing this I bought a vehicle to travel the east coast (silly I know). Now I have a car sitting in Cairns that I can't do anything about.

I left Australia last week when my WHV expired and flew to Japan to apply for tourist visa, now I am in limbo wondering what to do.

When I applied the only information I submitted was my flight leaving Brisbane, should I reapply with a cover letter, bank account screenshot, onward travel etc?

Am I better off going to an Australian Embassy?

While the eVisitor visa for travel would be nice, most importantly for me is the car I just bought for $2500 that is just sitting in my ex landlords driveway. If I can't get a tourist visa is there any 1 week visas that would allow me to sort anything like this out?

Is there any advice you can give me? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any paperwork related to refusal which you can upload after blanking personal information?

Comment: Have a mate sell the car for you. It sounds like you aren't likely to be returning to Australia any time soon.

Comment: You couldn’t find time in two years? Then it wasn’t a priority, let someone sell the car.

Comment: Not sure why this has been flagged as off-topic. Although the asker has recently completed a long stay in Australia, this isn't what the question is about.

Answer (score 8):

As noted on the Department's web site on the [Working Holiday visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417/second-working-holiday-417#About):

> **Stay longer on a visitor visa**
>
> Generally we don't grant a visitor visa after you have been in Australia on a Work and Holiday visa.
>
> If you want to apply for a Visitor visa to stay longer in Australia and the Visitor visa would result in you staying longer than 12 consecutive months in Australia, you must:
>
> - show there are exceptional circumstances
> - apply for a Visitor visa from outside Australia
>
> For this visa, exceptional circumstances might be that a close family member in Australia has died or is seriously ill and you need to stay.

Given the circumstances, the refusal of your application for a visitor visa is completely expected.  The intention of the Working Holiday visa is for you to complete your travels around Australia within the 2 year visa period.  It is unlikely that selling your car would be considered an "exceptional circumstance" that would justify the grant of a visitor visa.

You will need to arrange for someone in Australia to sell your car on your behalf.  Assuming that the car is registered in Queensland, you can complete the [legal transfer of the car's registration](https://www.qld.gov.au/transport/registration/transfer/online) online.